# Android 4.2 'always on vpn' no internet access

Tags: android, vpn

I have configured an IPSEC vpn on my Samsung Nexus tablet (4.2), the VPN works perfectly fine when I connect it manually. I have full vpn and internet access.

However, when I set it to 'always on vpn' I lose internet connectivity. I can still access all local devices i.e servers / printers but nothing outside of the vpn network.

I can't ping any external addresses like 8.8.8.8 or access any websites that are not on the intranet.

I have been trying different things - setting forward routese etc but nothing seems to work so far.

Answer (score 1):

This is bug in Android 4.2+ firewall. You can try fix, available on Google Play and called [AlwaysOnVpnFix](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.microlana.android.alwaysonvpnfix). But because this fix recover firewall rules, root access is required. Else your must wait next Android release by Google ;'(